# Ruby rand() cannot accept variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a little baffled by this.

My end goal in a RoR project is to grab a single random profile from my database.

I was thinking it would be something like:

```
@profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(rand(User.count))
```

It kept throwing an error because `user_id` 0 doesn't exist, so I pulled parts of it out just to check out what's going on:

```
@r = rand(User.count)

<%= @r %>
```

This returns 0 every time. So what's going on? I registered 5 fake users and 5 related profiles to test this.

If I take `Profile.find_by_user_id(rand(User.count))` and rewrite it as

```
Profile.find_by_user_id(3)
```

it works just fine.

`User.count` is working too. So I think that `rand()` can't take an input other than a static integer.

Am I right? Whats going on?

Comment: rand(User.count) works for me.

Comment: Really? Ok hmm. I'll have to see whats going on. Maybe I'm missing something critical.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andrew. Re-reading my own question got me confused sometimes too =D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
Profile.first(:offset => rand(Profile.count))
```

As a database ages, especially one with user records, there will be gaps in your ID field sequence. Trying to grab an ID at random will have a potential to fail because you might try to randomly grab one that was deleted.

Instead, if you count the number of records, then randomly go to some offset into the table you will sidestep the possibility of having missing IDs, and only be landing on existing records.

The following example from the OPs question could run into some problems unless the integrity of the database is watched very carefully:

```
profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(rand(User.count))
```

The problem is, there's a possibility for the User table to be out of sync with the Profile table, allowing them to have different numbers of records. For instance, if `User.count` was 3 and there were two records in Profile there's potential for a failed lookup resulting in an exception.

Comment: Perfect. Works very well. I chose this as the best answer because it side steps database specific functions like RAND/RANDOM =)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I deliberately avoided DB specifics to keep it portable. It could be written to run entirely in the DBM but that would tie the query to a particular database. As is, it has to make two calls to the database, but they're very fast and shouldn't involve a search.

Comment: Doesn't always have to be fast. For example, Postgres is kind-of notorious for slow COUNT(*) queries.

Comment: Yes, but there are [known ways](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) for speeding Postgres counts up. Also [http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2005-01/msg00247.php](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2005-01/msg00247.php)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why rand(i) isn't working as you expect (it works fine for me), but this isn't a good way to find a random profile regardless; if a profile is ever deleted, or there are any users without profiles, then this will fail.

I don't think there's an efficient way to do this in Rails using ActiveRecord. For a small number of users, you could just do Profile.find_all() and select a random profile from that array, but you'd probably be better off doing something like

```
@profile = Profile.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1").first
```

There are many other questions on StackOverflow about how to select a random record in SQL; I'd say this is the easiest, but if you're concerned about efficiency then have a look around and see if there's another implementation you like better.

EDIT: find_by_sql returns an array, so you need to do .first to get a single Profile.

Comment: I'll try this out. It never occured to me that people deleting their profiles would mess things up....ha I need to start writing test cases.

Comment: The way he's doing it is the best (generating the random number in Ruby and then searching for it in the `id` column) -- it takes constant time to actually find the row he wants. Doing it your way requires a full table scan to assign random numbers, and an O(n log n) sort before it can return the one row he needs.

Comment: @Ken Bloom this is true. The difference is that mine actually works =), whereas the OP's has the shortcomings that I mentioned. DanneManne's is similar and more Rubyish, but finding by a random ID is dangerous. You could wrap it in a while loop and keep searching until you find one, which would be faster for complete data sets but slower for ones with many missing rows (and potentially could be making many database requests instead of just one).

Comment: There are solutions for that. If there were many missing IDs, but making a full table scan for every query that needed a random row was too time intensive, I'd create another indexed column of IDs where the ids were kept sequential by a cronjob that did the table scan once a day. (The decision on which way to select random rows would depend on the characteristics of the data.)

Answer (score 1):

When I want to get a random record in Rails, I go something like this:

```
@profile = Profile.first(:order => "RAND()")
```

This usually works, but from what I've read earlier, the RAND() command is specific to MySQL or at least not database independent. Others might use RANDOM().

Answer (score -3):

## Finding By ID IN Rails is Redundant

```
@profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(rand(User.count))
#This is redudent, all you need to code is: 
@profile = Profile.find(rand(User.count)) #default for Rails is ID
```

The error message based on `0` is probably because of RAILS `Conventions Over Configuration` sensible defaults which are just rules people agree upon.

And when using rails there is no reason to have a user as 0, it always starts at 1 which I attribute to DHH trying to be more readable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with his question as far as I can tell. I agree that Profile.find(rand_int) is a more sensible than Profile.find_by_user_id(rand_it), but find_by_user_id isn't "redundant" in any real sense. I also have no idea what the rest of your post is talking about.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to make the post make more sense. I call Profile.find_by_user_id because there are 2 columns, id and user_id. I want to select the row based on the user_id column. So, its very necessary.